# All commands saying "FATAL: kernel too old" after pacman -Syu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, archlinux

I got a OpenVZ-based machine. And I updated the system:

```
pacman -Syu
```

And it got dead. Almost all executing commands says:

```
FATAL: kernel too old
```

And ssh is dead now.
Trying this on VNC:

```
cd /home
cd: /home: No such file or directory
```

Is this upgrade broke a system component? And how to fix it?

The upgrade includes those following packages:

```
binutils-2.29.0-1 expat-2.2.4-1 fakeroot-1.22-1 gcc-7.2.0-2
gcc-libs-7.2.0-2 glibc-2.26-3 iproute2-4.13.0-1
libtool-2.4.6+40+g6ca5e224-1 libxml2-2.9.5+6+g07e227ed-1
libxslt-1.1.29+42+gac341cbd-2 linux-api-headers-4.12.7-1
mesa-17.1.8-2 mkinitcpio-23-2 ncurses-6.0+20170902-1
p11-kit-0.23.8-1 pacman-mirrorlist-20170907-1 sudo-1.8.21.p2-1
ffmpeg-1:3.3.3-2 file-5.32-1 opus-1.2.1-1 python-pip-9.0.1-2
```

Comment: try an :  pwd to known where you are on the path of your shell. Here what you should do https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_Panics https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=39464

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  This may be more appropriate on https://unix.stackexechange.com . ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I've seen that *"kernel too old"* message (a few days ago) when I used a toolchain (to build the apps) that was built with kernel headers more recent than the kernel that was installed/executing.  I.E. the toolchain was built with kernel 3.10 headers, and the target was running a 3.6 kernel.  Rebuilding the apps with an older toolchain solved the issue.